# Blank file in Tee-Object file Powershell

Tags: powershell, output

Why is it that I am getting a blank file when I TEE-Object output this script, I see output on the screen?

```
$Computers = (gc C:\Scripts\Computers.txt)

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) 
{
$Computer
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { winmgmt -standalonehost }

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { if (Get-Service "UALSVC" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){ Stop-Service UALSVC -Force } }
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { if (Get-Service "MMS" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){ Stop-Service MMS -Force } }
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { if (Get-Service "iphlpsvc" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){ Stop-Service iphlpsvc -Force } }
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { if (Get-Service "hpqams" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){ Stop-Service hpqams -Force } }
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { if (Get-Service "wscsvc" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){ Stop-Service wscsvc -Force } }

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { Restart-Service winmgmt -Force }

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { if (Get-Service "hpqams" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){ Start-Service hpqams } }
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { if (Get-Service "iphlpsvc" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){ Start-Service iphlpsvc } }
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { if (Get-Service "MMS" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){ Start-Service MMS } }
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { if (Get-Service "UALSVC" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){ Start-Service UALSVC } }
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock { if (Get-Service "wscsvc" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){ Start-Service wscsvc } }

} Tee-Object -file c:\Scripts\WMI-Output.txt
```

Comment: `& { foreach (...) {...} } | Tee-Object ...`

Comment: Just an observation - all of the service manipulation could be done over RPC using the -ComputerName parameter of Get-Service/Stop-Service/Start-Service.

Answer (score 0):

As [PetSerAl hints at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41964700/blank-file-in-tee-object-file-powershell#comment71108425_41964700), you can't pipe output directly from a `foreach(){}` loop. You have a couple of options here:

Wrap in sub-expression:

```
$(foreach($i in 1..10){
  $i * $i
}) | Tee-Object -File C:\Scripts\Squares.txt
```

Wrap in a scriptblock:

```
&{
  foreach($i in 1..10){
    $i * $i
  }
} | Tee-Object -File C:\Scripts\Squares.txt
```

Use `ForEach-Object` instead of `foreach(){}`:

```
1..10 | ForEach-Object {
  $i * $i
} | Tee-Object -File C:\Scripts\Squares.txt
```

---

Your script can also be grossly simplified:

```
Get-Content C:\Scripts\Computers.txt |ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock { 
        # Enable winmgmt standalone mode
        winmgmt -standalonehost 

        # Stop services
        Get-Service UALSVC,MMS,iphlpsvc,hpqams,wscsvc -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |Stop-Service -Force

        # Restart winmgmt 
        Restart-Service winmgmt -Force 

        # Start services
        Get-Service hpqams,iphlpsvc,MMS,UALSVC,wscsvc -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |Start-Service -Force
    }
} | Tee-Object -FilePath c:\Scripts\WMI-Output.txt
```